# How can I build all build.xml (.java) files under a directory

Tags: ant, build, subdirectory

We needed to automate testing that all of the Java samples we ship compile properly. We need it to build all files without our listing each one. Listing each one means if someone forgets to add a new one (which will happen someday), explicit calls will miss it. By walking all build.xml files, we always get everything.

Doing this is pretty easy:

1. Install the samples on a clean VM (that we revert back to the snapshot for each test run).
2. Create a build.xml file that calls all the build.xml files installed.
3. Use ant to run the generated build.xml

Step 2 requires a means to generate the build.xml file. Is there any way to tell ant to run all build.xml files under a sub-directory or to create a build.xml that calls all the underlying build.xml files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you want to do is run the same build process for a number of sub-projects that (hopefully) follow a standard layout pattern.

If that's the case, you can create a single build.xml that knows how to compile those projects, and make a top-level build script which finds all the sub directories, then calls the common build script in each one.  [Subant was taylor-made for this](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/subant.html), and doesn't require a magic C# program to generate scripts in each directory.

Answer (score 0):

We couldn't find anything so we wrote a program that creates a build.xml that calls all build.xml files under a directory. Full solution is at [Windward Wrocks](http://blogs.windward.net/davidt/2012/12/02/build-all-build-xml-java-files-under-a-directory/) (my blog).

The code is (yep, using C# to create a build file for Java):

```
using System; 
using System.IO; 
using System.Text; 
using System.Xml; 
using System.Xml.Linq; 


namespace BuildJavaTestScript 
{ 
    public class Program 
    { 
        /// <summary> 
        /// Build build.xml for all build.xml files in sub-directories. 
        /// </summary> 
        /// <param name="args">Optional: build.xml root_folder</param> 
        public static void Main(string[] args) 
        { 
            string projFile = Path.GetFullPath(args.Length > 0 ? args[0] : "build.xml"); 
            string rootDirectory = Path.GetFullPath(args.Length > 1 ? args[1] : Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()); 
            Console.Out.WriteLine(string.Format("Creating build file {0}", projFile)); 
            Console.Out.WriteLine(string.Format("Root directory {0}", rootDirectory)); 


            XDocument xdoc = new XDocument(); 
            XElement elementProject = new XElement("project"); 
            xdoc.Add(elementProject); 
            elementProject.Add(new XAttribute("name", "BuildAll")); 
            elementProject.Add(new XAttribute("default", "compile")); 


            XElement elementTarget = new XElement("target"); 
            elementProject.Add(elementTarget); 
            elementTarget.Add(new XAttribute("name", "compile")); 


            XElement elementEcho = new XElement("echo"); 
            elementTarget.Add(elementEcho); 
            elementEcho.Add(new XAttribute("message", "Build All: jdk = ${java.home}, version = ${java.version}")); 


            // add .sln files - recursively 
            AddBuildXmlFiles(elementTarget, rootDirectory, rootDirectory); 


            Console.Out.WriteLine("writing build file to disk"); 
            // no BOM 
            using (var writer = new XmlTextWriter(projFile, new UTF8Encoding(false))) 
            { 
                writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented; 
                xdoc.Save(writer); 
            } 


            Console.Out.WriteLine("all done"); 
        } 


        private static void AddBuildXmlFiles(XElement elementTarget, string rootDirectory, string folder) 
        { 


            // add build.xml files 
            foreach (string fileOn in Directory.GetFiles(folder, "build.xml")) 
            { 
                string filename = Path.GetFileName(fileOn); 
                string workingFolder; 
                if (folder.StartsWith(rootDirectory)) 
                { 
                    workingFolder = folder.Substring(rootDirectory.Length).Trim(); 
                    if ((workingFolder.Length > 0) && (workingFolder[0] == Path.DirectorySeparatorChar || workingFolder[0] == Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar)) 
                        workingFolder = workingFolder.Substring(1); 
                } 
                else 
                    workingFolder = folder; 
                if (workingFolder.Length == 0) 
                    continue; 


                XElement elementExec = new XElement("ant"); 
                elementExec.Add(new XAttribute("dir", workingFolder)); 
                elementExec.Add(new XAttribute("antfile", filename)); 
                elementTarget.Add(elementExec); 
            } 


            // look in sub-directories 
            foreach (string subDirectory in Directory.GetDirectories(folder)) 
                AddBuildXmlFiles(elementTarget, rootDirectory, subDirectory); 
        } 
    } 
}
```